# How to resolve the undefined property error message in the local module?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am not a programmer so this is a little out of my league.

When I submit a question using the [answers module](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers), I receive the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$field_answer_count in       
locale_field_node_form_submit() (line 410 of /home/******/public_html/modules/locale  
/locale.module).
```

I do not know how to apply patches, such as a patch as suggested in https://www.drupal.org/node/1062072.

Any suggestions about how to resolve this error?

Comment: This is probably best asked in the issue queue for the Answer module http://drupal.org/project/issues/answers?categories=All.

Comment: but its actually a problem with the core, i think??

Comment: Doesn't seem like it to me.  `field_answer_count` is clearly associated with the Answers module, so chances are Answers is doing something wrong or setting itself up incorrectly.

Comment: well the author of the answers module has said it's a problem with the core.  is there a good tutorial anywhere for applying a patch for a beginner?  thank you

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/1062072#comment-5043284

Comment: On the command line navigate to the `modules/locale/` directory and download the file http://drupal.org/files/locale.undefinedpropertystdClass-1062072-12c.patch.  Then, run `patch -p3 < locale.undefinedpropertystdClass-1062072-12c.patch`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4529/discussion-between-lester-peabody-and-hollyh)